# How do I sum the values of a Javascript array in an asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, protractor, angular-promise

I'm using Angularjs Protractor for e2e tesing, and I'm trying the sum the values in a column. Inside the loop I can print out each value fine, but I can't figure out how to add them all. If I try to return total after the for loop, it's undefined.

```
function getTotal() {
  ptor.findElements(protractor.By.className('col33')).then(function(promColCells) {
    var total;
    for (var i = 2; i < promColCells.length; i += 2) {
      promColCells[i].getText().then(function(promCellString) {
        total += parseFloat(promCellString);
      });
    }
    return total;
  });
};
```

Comment: Are these operations async?  If they are, you simply can't synchronously return the total from a series of async operations?  If the operations aren't async, then I'm trying to figure out why you're even trying to use promises as there must be a simpler way.

Comment: The operations are async, that's what I'm mostly confused about.

Comment: Then, you simply cannot EVER synchronously return the `total` from `getTotal()` because it simply isn't done yet when `getTotal()` returns.  You will need to either have `getTotal()` return a promise and resolve that promise when the `total` is done being calculated or have `getTotal()` take a callback and call that callback and pass it the total when it's done calculating.  You have to restructure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protractor has a buil-in map function.

I would recommend you to do something like this:

```
function getTotal() {
  // The same as element.all(by.css('.col33')). It will return
  // a promise that resolves to an array os strings.
  return $$('.col33').map(function(cell){
    return cell.getText();
  }).
  then(function(values){
     // Values is an Array.<string> parse the ints and return the value.
     var result = 0;
     values.forEach(function(val){
       result += parseInt(val, 10);
     });
     return result;
  });
};

getTotal.then(function(total) {
});
```

Answer (score 6):

The other (now deletec) answer has the right idea but bulky and incorrect promise code. Using `$q.all` (Which is Promise.all in ES6 complaint promise implementations is how we wait for an array of promises to complete:

```
function getTotal() {
    // we return the continuation here
    return ptor.findElements(protractor.By.className('col33')).then(function(cells) {
        // wait for all cells  
        return $q.all(cells.map(function(cell){ return cell.getText()}));
    }).then(function(cellTexts){
        return cellTexts.reduce(function(x,y){ return x + Number(y);},0);
    });
}
```

Alternatively, if you're not an `Array#reduce` fan you can sum with a for loop.

Then, usage is something like:

```
getTotal().then(function(total){
    alert(total); // total value available here
});
```

---

Note, an external promise library like Bluebird would let you do:

```
return Promise.cast(ptor.findElements(protractor.By.className('col33')))
    .map(function(cell){ return cell.getText(); })
    .reduce(function(x,y){ return x+Number(y); });
```

Which is even cleaner.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand it now.  Is there an extra/missing brace or something though? I'm getting an `unexpected token }` error.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea, I typed it in Stack Overflow, didn't test it - just wanted to pass a point, lemme hunt it down one sec.

Comment: Might be missing a `)` on line 5?